# Discord.py Uppercase And Lowercase

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the command to work when a letter is uppercase and lowercase, but I don't know how to do it. Please help me. Example:Ping PINg PiNg

```
@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! ``{round(client.latency * 1000)}``')
```

Comment: Which letter uppercase or lowercase? Did you try looking into discord documentation? You have to take user argument from variables, parse it and then use conditional checks to check for uppercase or lowercase, this is comparatively simple case so you might try looking around before asking!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify case insensitivity when you instantiate your bot/client:

```py
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True)
```

It defaults to false, but setting it to `True` will allow any case combination of commands.

And the equivalent when creating commands in `on_message`:

```py
if message.content.lower().startswith("!ping"):
    # do stuff
```

---

**References:**

- [`Bot.case_insensitive`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.case_insensitive)
- [`Message.content`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.content)

Comment: how would you do this with event

Comment: @BurnDownTheWorld You can use `.lower()` or `.upper()` to make it case-insensitive (just make sure the string you're comparing it against is also lowercase or uppercase respectively!) - there's an example in the answer!